# Setting a static IP on latest Jessie

Tags: networking, dhcp

I've had no end of trouble setting a static IP for eth0 in the latest release.  I need a static IP for eth0 because I want to SSH into my Pi when I take it into the field without any wifi.  I followed this tutorial: [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip)  but haven't had any luck using dhcpcd.conf to do the configuration.  I just end up with an autoconfig address. What am I doing wrong?  This is the dhcpcd.conf that I am using:

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU.
# Some interface drivers reset when changing the MTU so disabled by default.
#option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
# server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname

eth0
static ip_address = 192.168.20.2/24
static routers = 192.168.20.1
static domain_name_servers = 192.168.20.1
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example code, you have:

`eth0
static ip_address = 192.168.20.2/24
static routers = 192.168.20.1
static domain_name_servers = 192.168.20.1`

The correct syntax is:

`interface eth0
static ip_address = 192.168.20.2/24
static routers = 192.168.20.1
static domain_name_servers = 192.168.20.1`

Which is the addition of the qualifier `interface` before `eth0`.